# Using multiple trackers with segment.io

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, kissmetrics

We are using two trackers on our website GaTracker and KISSmetrics on our website. We are using Segment.io as an even abstraction layer. Now we want to extend the functionality of our script that is for some events I want to call GaTracker and for some events I want to call KISSmetrics, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I'd like to mention that [Segment.io](https://segment.io) uses analytics.js as the javascript client, which is open source and you can check out the [source code](http://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js) anytime.

If you enable GA and KM on Segment.io, analytics.js will bring the GA and KM snippets onto the page, so you can still interact with the "_gaq" or "_kmq" globals as you have done in the past. You'll want to wrap your calls to the globals using the [analytics.ready(..) method](https://segment.io/libraries/analytics.js#ready), like so:

```
analytics.ready(function () {
    _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '1234',           // transaction ID - required
    'Acme Clothing',  // affiliation or store name
    '11.99',          // total - required
    '1.29',           // tax
    '5',              // shipping
    'San Jose',       // city
    'California',     // state or province
    'USA'             // country
  ]);
});
```

analytics.ready(..) will call the callback function when the _gaq and km variables have been loaded (think of it like the jquery $.ready document ready handler).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `integrations` key in the options argument for `alias`, `group`, `identify`, `page` and `track`

```js
analytics.identify('019mr8mf4r', {
  email: 'achilles@segment.com',
  plan: 'Premium'
}, {
  integrations: {
    'All': false,
    'Mixpanel': true,
    'KISSMetrics': true,
    'Google Analytics': false
  }
});
```

https://segment.com/docs/libraries/analytics.js/#selecting-integrations